# Where can I find a great gemara shiur online that doesn’t require background knowledge?

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, adult-learning

I am looking to recommend to a friend a deep and interesting shiur in gemara online that doesn’t require any background knowledge or use of Hebrew terms.

Comment: Contact Ohr Sameach.

Comment: @pcoz might mean online

Comment: Online or live?

Comment: Most shiurim for beginners focus more on establishing competency than the depth of the ideas. It's a wiser course in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worthwhile checking out the beginner series of shiurim on the Chabad website [here](https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/audio_cdo/aid/1677756/jewish/Talmud-for-Beginners.htm) - it includes handouts as wells to make it more easily understandable.

The first session begins [here](https://www.chabad.org/multimedia/audio_cdo/aid/1186322/jewish/Talmud-Study-Lesson-1.htm).

Hatzlacha (best of luck!)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Lakewood Daf Yomi](https://app.lakewooddafyomi.com/browse/shiurim) will work, Sruly Bornstein is a great teacher, gives a lot of background and explains most (Hebrew) terms.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really recommended to learn gemara by yourself, or with little background. The least one should do is join some sort of class that teaches *how to learn* first, and then later learn gemara with a chavruta and in reference to some sort of shiur.

[Professionals Beis Medrash](https://pbmuk.org/) is a program in many cities that caters for just this.

May I take this opportunity to recommended Koren gemara (which is all uploaded to [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/texts/Talmud)). Many people when they first see it are amazed, as Steinsaltz translates the gemara and fills the in-between words to convert the brevity of Talmudic notes into full prose, taking into account commentaries. It should be noted that it of course has to be selective to which commentaries it chooses and one should always strive to get a complete picture by following the above recommedations.